# How do i open the pickadate.js calender on top of the input field

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, pickadate

I have a problem in pickadate calender. I found an issue in pickadate at end of the page please go through the attachment . I have to open the pickadate calendar top of the input field while the input field at the end of the browser.

[image]

I have tried below code:

```
$('#description_award').pickadate({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    formatSubmit: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    min: scriptDate,
    max: maxDate,
    drops: "up"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the root for the picker by using the container-option i.e.: `container: '#my-root'`. You can put that root element anywhere.  And then you can target the picker with css. for example `#my-root .picker__holder { bottom:0; }` would make it appear above the root (because it's absolutely positioned)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.datepicker').pickadate({container:"#my-root"});
});
```

```css
html { padding-top: 150px; /* just for stack-overflow */ }
#my-root { outline: 1px solid red; /* just a visual clue */ }
#my-root .picker__holder { bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/compressed/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/compressed/picker.date.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/compressed/themes/classic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/compressed/themes/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="my-root">
    <!-- datepicker will appear where this element is -->
</div>
<input class="datepicker" placeholder="clickme">
```